# SharePoint 2013 Search - What Permissions are required to properly administer a Site Collection

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search, permissions, managed-property

I am providing search results for a project.  I'm leveraging the Term Store, Result Sources, Result Types, custom Display Templates... Everything.  Everything works perfectly.  This was all done on SharePoint Online, where I am Site Collection Administrator

A colleague who is a Site Collection Owner (SharePoint 2013) is missing key features such as the ability to create Managed Properties, unable to upload display templates etc.

What permission are needed to create an end to end search solution in a Site Collection if you are not a Site Collection Admin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A user need full control to create managed properties and upload the display template.

If user added into the Site collection Owners group then it will get full control on the site collection level (unless someone change the permission level).

in site settings of Site collection, he can click on schema under search.

Comment: Waqas,
I have a user that is a SharePoint 2013 Site Collection Owner, and he can't create a managed property.  Nor does he have access to the Crawl Schedule.  I don't think Owner gives you full rights.

Comment: how you accessing it? can he see the Site settings > under Search -- Schema option?

Comment: on prem, we cant access crawl schedule from site collection.